# Whether there is such a derivable function

Tags: derivatives

Whether there is a derivable function and it takes a rational value at every rational point where the derivative is an irrational number？
I don't have any idea. Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For the function $f(x)=0$, the claim:

> For all $x\in \mathbb R$, if $f'(x)$ is irrational, then $f(x)$ is rational

is true, so the answer is yes.

Comment: I mean if $x$ is rational, then $f(x) is rational, but $f'(x) is irrational$